# Can I have one XML Schema (XSD) include another XML-Schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, include

I currently have two XSD schemes and one is a "light" version of the other. Right now I have everything in the "light" version repeated in the "complete" schema, but this becomes a pain when I need to make a change, and it goes against the DRY principle anyways, so I was wondering if there was an element that served to include another schema into a schema, so I can have my "complete" inherit from the "light" schema to reduce maintenance hurdles.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There are two methods for this.

`<xsd:include schemaLocation="pathToFile" />` should be used for including files of the same namespace.

`<xsd:import namespace="namespace" schemaLocation="pathToFile" />` should be used for include files in a different namespace. Usually you will specify the namespace given as the targetNamespace of the imported schema.

Answer (score 5):

Use the <include> element, see for example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_include.asp).